# What is the expected value of this formula?

Tags: probability, permutations

Let $Π = (π_1,π_2,...,π_n)$ be a random permutation of {1, 2,..., n}.
What is the expected value of 
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |\pi_i-i|?
$$

Comment: Use linearity of expectation.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out like that: E=1*(1/n)+2*(1/n)+...+n*(1/n)=(1+n)/2. Is it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linearity of expectation is your friend:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lvert \pi_i-i\rvert\right]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\lvert\pi_i-i\rvert.
$$
So, you just have to figure out these intermediate expectations.  To that end, note that
$$
\mathbb{E}\lvert \pi_i-i\vert=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lvert k-i\rvert P(\pi_i=k).
$$
What is $P(\pi_i=k)$? This is a simple matter of counting the number of permutations which map $i\mapsto k$ for a fixed $i$ and $k$ (which won't depend on either $i$ or $k$, as it happens).  Once you've done this, it is a matter of manipulating the sum.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Small comment: by symmetry it suffices to only deal with the case $i=1$, which helps remove the absolute values.